# Swift Read Dictionary from plist

Tags: swift, ios8

In My project i have this Dictionary in a Plist File

```
dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
```

I normaly Read the Dictionary in this mode

```
var dictRead = data!["dict"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

And i have this result

```
[cola : 10, fanta : 12, sprite : 8]
```

But if i want Read the Dictionary as to String, Int ?
I have tried with

```
  var dictRead = data!["dict"] as? Dictionary<String, Int>
```

But i have this Error

```
  lenghtAndRefCount = (unsigned int) 197132388
  characters (unsigned [])

  Dict ([String:Int]) dict = {}
```

Update i have solve in this mode

```
 var dict = data!["dict"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
 for dictValue in dict.values {
 var someNumb: Int = ("\(dictValue)").toInt()!

 }
```

Comment: You are not providing enough information. You have to explain what your data object is, and post the error message. Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: The error message has to be more than `Dict ([String:Int])`.

Comment: How are you reading your data out of the plist?

Comment: Where are you getting `data` from? Why are you treating it like a dictionary?